# Downgrade Geth from 1.6 to 1.59 to have solc integrated in Geth

Tags: go-ethereum, testnets, solc, compilation

I have this project on ropsten testnt that don't want to keep developing but keep on running. Since they took solc out of Geth on v1.6, I get the error method eth_compilesolidity does not exist. Is there an easy way around it? If I downgrade Geth to v1.5 would my project work without the need to change anything and will I need to delete the testnet blockchain I already have? Also what is the correct way to downgrade geth to v1.5 on linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project should be fine when you'll downgrade the binary to 1.5.9. Although, I'd recommend taking a backup before.

You can get the source code of 1.5.9 from Release page of the go-ethereum project https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.5.9 and build in for your system.

Update:

I synchronized full Ropsten blockchain on 1.6.1 and downgraded binary to 1.5.9 built from source. After that, I've started the client. The client is working.

```
ubuntu@test1:~$ geth --testnet
I0528 18:39:48.909724 node/config.go:445] Failed to start Ledger hub, disabling: libusb: unknown error [code -99]
I0528 18:39:48.909814 cmd/utils/flags.go:613] WARNING: No etherbase set and no accounts found as default
I0528 18:39:48.909841 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata
I0528 18:40:47.701190 ethdb/database.go:176] closed db:/home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata
I0528 18:40:47.702531 node/node.go:176] instance: Geth/v1.5.9-stable/linux/go1.6.3
I0528 18:40:47.702595 ethdb/database.go:83] Allotted 128MB cache and 1024 file handles to /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth/chaindata
I0528 18:40:47.791896 core/genesis.go:95] Genesis block already in chain. Writing canonical number
I0528 18:40:47.793168 eth/backend.go:276] Successfully wrote custom genesis block: 41941023680923e0fe4d74a34bdac8141f2540e3ae90623718e47d66d1ca4a2d
I0528 18:40:47.794628 eth/backend.go:187] Protocol Versions: [63 62], Network Id: 3
I0528 18:40:47.798475 eth/backend.go:215] Chain config: {ChainID: 3 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 0 EIP155: 10 EIP158: 10}
I0528 18:40:47.807987 core/blockchain.go:219] Last header: #1121267 [37787a3c…] TD=205694086442412
I0528 18:40:47.808046 core/blockchain.go:220] Last block: #1121267 [37787a3c…] TD=205694086442412
I0528 18:40:47.808059 core/blockchain.go:221] Fast block: #1121267 [37787a3c…] TD=205694086442412
I0528 18:40:47.832924 p2p/server.go:340] Starting Server
I0528 18:40:50.195813 p2p/discover/udp.go:227] Listening, enode://1943e86b5ef0b79104fe150c40c8492b9b362d560af30964a34a4fe9f75451ec051c23b97f37ea2cb6ed7ccf450e0baf8c656292abe3caddf3134564cd6a1e58@[::]:30303
I0528 18:40:50.196804 p2p/server.go:608] Listening on [::]:30303
I0528 18:40:50.197068 node/node.go:341] IPC endpoint opened: /home/ubuntu/.ethereum/testnet/geth.ipc
I0528 18:41:09.981681 eth/downloader/downloader.go:326] Block synchronisation started
I0528 18:41:10.171278 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer 96fa95f526f5839e [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #1031267 [00000000…] <= #1031267 limit
I0528 18:42:02.066483 eth/downloader/downloader.go:723] Peer bb8f92cc0157584f [hs 0.00/s, bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack: #1031267 [00000000…] <= #1031267 limit
```

Comment: does this require deleting the blockchain and re-synchronizing it afterwards?

Comment: @PetrosM I'll synchronize ropsten, downgrade binary, and start it with downgraded binary, and will let you know

Comment: you don't need to re-synchronize. just keep your datadir/do not overwrite it.

Comment: @PetrosM I've made the test with downgrading and updated my answer with the result. There is no need to re-syncronize. You can mark the post as solved.

Comment: Hi @IgorBarinov I didn't have time to try it myself until now. I donwloaded the source, cd into the 1.5.9 version, typed make geth. Then go to build/bin and type geth --help and see the versin is still 1.6.. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @PetrosM you should run `./geth --help` to run from the local directory or the system will use system path

Comment: yes, i thought it would execute it automatically. This worked thank you very much!